# assigning sequential ranks to data with multiple ties in R

Tags: r, ranking

I am trying to rank counts, conditioned by two factors in a dataframe. However I would like to have a special treatment of the ties. If two values are equaly, I want them to have an equal tie value. However the next value in the rank should have the next integer rank.

Where I'm stuck is when I have the get the dataframe of unique values, conditional on the factor species. (In my actual data set it is conditional on three factors).

```
species <- c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 4))
df <- data.frame(species, count = c("1", "1", "5", "1", "3", "3", "4"))

df$rank <- ave(df$count, df$species, FUN = rank)#doesnt get the output i'd like

#desired output
df$rank.good <- c("1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "3")
df
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is your desired output, as `df.3` has `NA` as one of its ranks. Maybe you need `dense_rank` function from the `dplyr` package?

Comment: Just tried to clarify, sorry I thought I had gotten the first part of the code to work. I think dense_rank is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your data in its current form you have two problems, one of which is an R syntactic concern and the other is a "semantic" concern. The syntactic concern has been raised by @ARobertson who is really suggesting that you convert the "count" column to character. That will prevent the creation of spurious `<NA>`'s but won't solve the semantic problem of what to do if this is more than just a toy problem. If those count values are coming in as character values then sorting as characters will make the ordering: 1,10,11,12,...,19,2,20,21, .... So immediately after converting factors with `as.character`, you also need an `as.numeric` step, even if you resort to using dplyr::dense_rank:

```
dense_rank <-   # copied from pkg::dplyr
 function (x) 
 {   r <- rank(x)
     match(r, sort(unique(r)))
 }
df$rank.good <- ave(as.numeric(as.character(df$count)), df$species, FUN = dense_rank)
```

If you really want these to be character class you can wrap an outer `as.character(.)` around the `ave` function-call.

Comment: Sorry for the simultaneous editing. The dense_rank function is much more succinct.

Comment: Neither your answer nor `plyr::dense_rank` would solve the  problematic sorting of character values unless lexical-ordering were the goal that the questioner had in mind. Seems very likely that he didn't expect `12` to be less than `2` if these were "counts".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# added more tests that are not sequential and fixed up data.frame
species <- c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 4),rep("c",10))
df <- data.frame(species, count = c("1", "1", "5", "1", "3", "3", "4",'1','7','3','3','7','2','10','3','11','2'),stringsAsFactors = F)
df$count <- as.numeric(df$count)

# solution
df$rank <- ave(df$count, df$species, FUN = function(x){
  r <- rank(x,ties.method = 'min')
  as.numeric(factor(rank(sort(r))))[r]
  })
```

Comment: That works! I'm confused as to why this didn't work before: `df$rank.min <- ave(df$count, df$species, FUN=rank, ties.method="min")`

Comment: I don't believe ave() has a ...= argument like most of the *apply family that lets you pass in additional arguments. The ties.method is silently ignored and instead uses the default 'average'.